# How to combine values of objects with common key in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, underscore.js

I'm trying to merge some items in a JSON array, based on one of the keys. I want to group by the 'metric', and then I need to look at all the time/value data in 'rounded_counts', and if the times are the same, the values need to be added together. Here is the source data:

```
let sourceData = [
  {
    "metric": "Approved",
    "rounded_counts": [
      { "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 3 }, 
      { "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 5 }
    ]
  },
  {
    "metric": "Approved",
    "rounded_counts": [
      { "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 28 },
      { "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 28 }
    ]
  },
  {
    "metric": "Quarantine",
    "rounded_counts": [
      { "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 1 },
      { "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 2 }
    ]
  }
];
```

and here is the desired output required for the Highcharts graphing library - notice how the 2 metrics called 'Approved' have had their values merged

Underscore, and/or ES6 can be used - Thanks in advance!

```
let chartData = [
  {
    "name": "Approved",
    "data": [
      [ "2017-11-16 15:10:00", 30 ],
      [ "2017-11-16 15:11:00", 33 ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Quarantine",
    "data": [
      [ "2017-11-16 15:10:00", 1 ],
      [ "2017-11-16 15:11:00", 2 ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: You have to iterate your JSON and build your own

Comment: @Zooly That's not [JSON](http://json.org) but an array of objects

Comment: @Andreas I've tried iterating over the metric name to create an array, I've tried storing the values in ES6 maps, but I was hoping a fresh set of eyes would see something I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my two cents.

```js
const sourceData = [
  {
    "metric": "Approved",
    "rounded_counts": [
      { "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 3 },
      { "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 5 }
    ]
  },

  {
    "metric": "Approved",
    "rounded_counts": [
      { "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 28 },
      { "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 28 }
    ]
  },

  {
    "metric": "Quarantine",
    "rounded_counts": [
      { "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 1 },
      { "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 2 }
    ]
  }
];

function mergeDatas(currentObject, rounded_counts) {
  return rounded_counts.map(x => {
    if (currentObject.data.some(y => y[0] === Object.keys(x)[0])) {
      const miniArray = currentObject.data.find(y =>
      y[0] === Object.keys(x)[0]);

      miniArray[1] += x[Object.keys(x)[0]];

      return miniArray;
    }

    return x;
  })
}

const result = sourceData.reduce((tmp, x) => {
  if (tmp.some(t => t.name === x.metric)) {
    const currentObject = tmp.find(y => y.name === x.metric);

    mergeDatas(currentObject, x.rounded_counts);

    return tmp;
  }

  tmp.push({
    name: x.metric,
    data: x.rounded_counts.map(y => {
      const key = Object.keys(y)[0];

      return [key, y[key]];
    }),
  });

  return tmp;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at something like this :

```
[{
      "metric": "Approved",
        "rounded_counts": [
          { "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 3 },
          { "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 5 }
        ]
    },
    ...
].reduce((tmp, x) => {
  const ptr = tmp;

  // look if it exist
  const index = ptr.findIndex(y => y.name === x.metric);

  // It exist
  if (index !== -1) {
    ptr[index].data = addSimilarDatesValues([
      ...ptr[index].data,
      ...x.rounded_counts,
    ]);

    return ptr;
  }

  // it doesn't
  ptr.push({
    name: x.metric,
    data: x.rounded_counts.map(y => [
        Object.keys(y)[0],
        y[Object.keys(y)[0]],
    ]),
  });

  return ptr;
}, []);
```

---

```
/**
 * We have this in entry
 *
 * [
 *   { "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 3 }, 
 *   { "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 5 },
 *   { "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 28 },
 *   { "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 28 },
 * ]
 *
 * Or this
 *
 * [
 *   [ "2017-11-16 15:10:00", 3 ], 
 *   [ "2017-11-16 15:11:00", 5 ],
 * ]
 *
 *
 * WARNING: Here you can have already converted data
 * It happens when we push the first item into the list
 *
 * We return this
 *
 * [
 *   [ "2017-11-16 15:10:00", 31 ], 
 *   [ "2017-11-16 15:11:00", 33 ],
 * ]
 * 
 */
```

---

```
const addSimilarDatesValues = (array) => {
  return array.reduce((tmp, x) => {
    const ptr = tmp;

    // Handle the already converted data
    const isArray = x instanceof Array;

    const keyToStore = isArray ? x[0] : Object.keys(x)[0];
    const valueToStore = isArray ? x[1] : x[Object.keys(x)[0]];

    // Look if there is a date already in tmp
    const index = ptr.findIndex(y => y[0] === keyToStore);

    // It's not
    if (index === -1) {
      // add a new entry for the date
      return [
        ...ptr,
        [
          keyToStore,
          valueToStore,
        ],
      ];
    }

    // It is - add the value into the already stored one
    ptr[index][1] += valueToStore;

    return ptr;
  }, []);
};
```

---

```js
const addSimilarDatesValues = (array) => {
  return array.reduce((tmp, x) => {
    const ptr = tmp;
    const isArray = x instanceof Array;

    const keyToStore = isArray ? x[0] : Object.keys(x)[0];
    const valueToStore = isArray ? x[1] : x[Object.keys(x)[0]];

    // Look if there is a date already in tmp
    const index = ptr.findIndex(y => y[0] === keyToStore);

    // It's not
    if (index === -1) {
      // add a new entry for the date
      return [
        ...ptr, [
          keyToStore,
          valueToStore,
        ],
      ];
    }

    // It is - add the value into the already stored one
    ptr[index][1] += valueToStore;

    return ptr;
  }, []);
};

const ret = [{
    "metric": "Approved",
    "rounded_counts": [{
        "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 3
      },
      {
        "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 5
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "metric": "Approved",
    "rounded_counts": [{
        "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 28
      },
      {
        "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 28
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "metric": "Quarantine",
    "rounded_counts": [{
        "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 1
      },
      {
        "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 2
      },
    ]
  }
].reduce((tmp, x) => {
  const ptr = tmp;

  // look if it exist
  const index = ptr.findIndex(y => y.name === x.metric);

  // It exist
  if (index !== -1) {
    ptr[index].data = addSimilarDatesValues([
      ...ptr[index].data,
      ...x.rounded_counts,
    ]);

    return ptr;
  }

  // it doesn't
  ptr.push({
    name: x.metric,
    data: x.rounded_counts.map(y => [
      Object.keys(y)[0],
      y[Object.keys(y)[0]],
    ]),
  });

  return ptr;
}, []);

console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though @Grégory's answer is quite elegant, it doesn't output the correct form. `data` contains an key/value object instead of an array of 2 elements with 1 key and 1 value.

Try this instead:

```
let sourceData = [
  {
    "metric": "Approved",
    "rounded_counts": [
      { "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 3 }, 
      { "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 5 }
    ]
  },
  {
    "metric": "Approved",
    "rounded_counts": [
      { "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 28 },
      { "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 28 }
    ]
  },
  {
    "metric": "Quarantine",
    "rounded_counts": [
      { "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 1 },
      { "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 2 }
    ]
  }
];

let charDataTmp = {}
let chartData = []

//uniqueify
sourceData.forEach(block => {
  if (!charDataTmp[block.metric])
  {
    charDataTmp[block.metric]={rounded_counts:{}}
  }
  block.rounded_counts.forEach(roundedCount => {
    let key = Object.keys(roundedCount)[0]
    if (!charDataTmp[block.metric].rounded_counts[key])
    {
      charDataTmp[block.metric].rounded_counts[key] = 0
    }
    charDataTmp[block.metric].rounded_counts[key] += roundedCount[key]
  })
})

//unfold
Object.keys(charDataTmp).forEach(nameGroup => {
  chartData.push({
    name: nameGroup,
    data: Object.keys(charDataTmp[nameGroup].rounded_counts).map(counts => {
      return [
        counts,
        charDataTmp[nameGroup].rounded_counts[counts]
      ]
    })
  })
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(chartData, null, 4))
```

Comment: I saw your comment and yes I totally forgot about it! I've made a change :)

Answer (score 0):

Because of the structure of your data, it looks like you are going to need to use some nested loops and comparisons. I don't think you can do this with the built in array functions in javascript. Try this:

```
    let sourceData = [{
      "metric": "Approved",
      "rounded_counts": [{
        "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 3
      }, {
        "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 5
      }]
    }, {
      "metric": "Approved",
      "rounded_counts": [{
        "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 28
      }, {
        "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 28
      }]
    }, {
      "metric": "Quarantine",
      "rounded_counts": [{
        "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 1
      }, {
        "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 2
      }]
    }];
    let chartData = [];

    function isSame(obj1, obj2) {
      if (obj1.metric && obj1.metric == obj2.metric &&
         obj1.rounded_counts && obj2.rounded_counts &&
         obj1.rounded_counts.length == obj2.rounded_counts.length) {
        var roundedCountsDifferent = false;
        for (var i in obj1.rounded_counts) {
          var count = 0;
          var key1;
          var key2;
          for (var j in obj1.rounded_counts[i]) {
            key1 = j;
            break;
          }
          for (var j in obj2.rounded_counts[i]) {
            key2 = j;
            break;
          }
          roundedCountsDifferent = key1 != key2;
          return !roundedCountsDifferent;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
    for (var i in sourceData) {
      var source = sourceData[i];
      var existingChart = null;
      for (var j in chartData) {
        if (isSame(source, chartData[j])) {
          existingChart = chartData[j];
          for (var k in source.rounded_counts) {
            var key;
            var val;
            for (var kv in source.rounded_counts[k]) {
              val = source.rounded_counts[k][kv];
              break;
            }
            for (var kv in existingChart.rounded_counts[k]) {
              existingChart.rounded_counts[k][kv] += val;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (!existingChart) {
        chartData.push(source);
      }
    }
    console.log(chartData);
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/h1n70m7s/1/

Comment: Me I'm pretty sure that yes :)

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are looking for. This is merging the two datasets, adding values from the second item that don't exist in the first.

There are a number of comments in there so you can follow along with the data as it is worked on.

```js
let sourceData = [
    {
        "metric": "Approved",
        "rounded_counts": [
            { "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 3 }, 
            { "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 5 }
        ]
    },
    {
        "metric": "Approved",
        "rounded_counts": [
            { "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 28 },
            { "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 28 },
            { "2017-11-16 15:12:00": 29 }
        ]
    },
    {
        "metric": "Quarantine",
        "rounded_counts": [
            { "2017-11-16 15:10:00": 1 },
            { "2017-11-16 15:11:00": 2 }
        ]
    }
];

let chartData = []; // our combined output Dataset

// map over the sourceData one item at a time. 
sourceData.map((item) => {
    let d = chartData.find(data => data.metric == item.metric);
    if ( d ) { // if an existing item exists
        //console.log("item exists"); console.log(d);

        // create a new array of the existing items
        rounded_counts = d.rounded_counts;

        // iterate all the rounded_counts in the current item
        item.rounded_counts.map((count) => {

            let key = Object.keys(count)[0]; // get the key for the current object, this would be the datetime
            // console.log("key: " + key);

            // check for any existing items with the same key (datetime)
            let additional = rounded_counts.find(data => Object.keys(data)[0] == key);
            // console.log(additional); // print the additional item raw

            if (additional) {
                // console.log(additional[Object.keys(additional)]); // print the additional items value, this is the value we will add to the existing item with the same "metric" and same value
                let Z = (count[key] + additional[Object.keys(additional)]); // add our 2 values together
                // console.log(Z);  // print this new value
                let newObj = {}; newObj[key] = Z; // create a new Object with the new value and existing key
                rounded_counts[rounded_counts.findIndex(data => Object.keys(data)[0] == key)] = newObj; // update the existing rounded_count item with our new object
            } else {
                rounded_counts.push(count);
            }
        });

        // set the exists items rounded_counts to our new array
        d.rounded_counts = rounded_counts;

    } else {
        chartData.push(item);
    }
});

// print the dataset so we can inspect the results
console.log(chartData);
```

Comment: -1 `rounded_counts = d.rounded_counts` is not a copy (and then save it back?). 1 letter variables. Sloppy indentation. Commented logs. `additional[Object.keys(additional)]` what? `Object.keys` returns an array, which gets stringified and used as a key of `additional`. Sorry, this code is a mess.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful critique. I cleaned up the sloppy indentation left over from the editor. The console.log is commented out to ensure the output of run snippet looks correct. Past that, I am not sure what you are hoping to achieve with your comment.

Comment: I've flagged both of your comments. Your choice to critique my answer was both rude and unsolicited. Additionally, it is doing nothing to help the original poster. I'm also not very concerned about having one answer downvoted, it was a good question and I had fun working out my answer. Again, I can only wonder what you hoped to gain with your comments.